# BIGINT value changes while inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working on a laravel project. I created migration for the table that contains following column:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('external_id')->nullable();
```

I also added seeder to fill my table with data. Inside seeder class I'm doing:

```
'external_id' => 154219795540098834,
```

After running migrations and seeding `external_id` value in the database is `154219795540098848`.

I have no idea what causes this problem.

Comment: In just MYSQL via HeidiSQL the issue is not reproducible. Maybe the bug is in laravel located. And what means `seeding` here? It the id in any why manipulated?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions It means running command: php artisan db:seed.

Comment: If possible just use an `VARCHR(20)` for the bigints, if the problem can not fixed.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I think I'll have to do this.

Comment: I just dont get why the number is not rounded or else but increased by 14? wired.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I've tried inserting different numbers and it doesn't always add 14. I don't get it.

Comment: Try it without laravel, if it works, then bugreport to laravel :-)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I think the problem is that PHP represents BIGINT as float.